# Effective desktop layout saving for developers?

Tags: layout, windows-8.1, desktop

I develop mostly in one of two layouts:

- Laptop with its native 1920x1080 resolution OR
- Laptop with attached 2nd monitor (with 1650x900 resolution)

Lets call the top one LAYOUT-A and the bottom one LAYOUT-B.

When I open the Delphi and Visual Studio IDEs (or Excel, or any other application) and set up the layout of the main window, debugging, find-and-replace windows, etc I find it all works nicely...until I switch between LAYOUT-A or LAYOUT-B. Then the main Windows desktop gets messed up (icons bunched up haphazardly) and the IDEs windows need to be reset.

This gets even worse if I have to connect to a projector with some low resolution like 1024x768 for a client demo! Then I face 10-20 minutes of painful resetting up!

Is there any way, perhaps early after boot, where I can tell Windows "Hey, I'm using LAYOUT-A today!" and then everything just works??

Using Windows 8.1 here.

Comment: This is an interesting question! But not on-topic here, as it has little to do with programming. It might be actually related to any application windows layout (if I got it right), not only the IDE ones. If that is so, it better fits to http://superuser.com/.

Comment: True, not specific to development. I just feel the pain because it takes a long time to get your IDE "just so" and as a developer, changing screen resolution can be regular as you move location a lot. Having asked the question on superuser I've got a recommendation of Desktop Restore (http://www.midiox.com/) which saves icons fine and works on Windows 8.1.  Happy to pass that on because it works well. Still looking for something for the application windows, though.